# Inheritance in classes Java

Tags: java, object, inheritance, constructor

```
class Foo {
    int number;
    public Foo(int x) {
        number = x;
        multiply();
    }
    public void multiply() {
        number = 2 * number;    
    }
    public int getNumber() {
        return number;
    }
}
class Bar extends Foo {
    int number;
    public Bar(int x,int y) {
        super(x);
        number = y;
        multiply();
    }
    public void multiply() {
        number = number * 3;
    } 
}
class Test {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        Foo foo = new Foo(42);
        Foo bar = new Bar(42,24);
        System.out.println(foo.getNumber() + "\n" + bar.getNumber());
    }
}
```

The output of this code is 84 and 42 but no matter how I trace it, I end up with 84 and 72. Can anyone explain this in detail.

Comment: Can you show how you trace it to get `72`?

Comment: 24*3 is indeed 72. I don't see the problem here ?

Comment: In the statement
    Foo bar  = new Bar(42,24);
the constructor of Bar is called which calls the constructor of Foo, which calls the multiply function which doubles Foo.number. Then Bar.number should be made 72 because multiply is called in its constructor which triples the value. However the answer is 42. Not 72.

Comment: you must overide the methode `getNumber()` becuase it gives you the number in the class Foo not the number in Bar class :)

Comment: @Stultuske, when I compile, the answer is 84 and 42. Not 84 and 72

Comment: @Maraboc: Or better, just don't have two separate `number` fields...

Comment: Basically, `Bar.number` is hiding `Foo.number`. You've got two separate fields. That's confusing, as you can tell...

Comment: @SudarshanSunder: I assume that's when you run it. I missunderstood your question. My guess, your issue is because you have separate number variables in both classes, what you shouldn't have, and have declared bar to be of type Foo

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a trace:

Calling `new Bar(42,4)`:

The `42` is passed to the `super` constructor. So it executes the body of:

```
public Foo(int x) {
    number = x;
    multiply();
}
```

The `number` it uses is its own `number` (the `Foo.number` which is hidden), but the `multiply()` it calls is the *overridden* one. Thus it calls:

```
public void multiply() {
    number = number * 3;
}
```

But this refers to `Bar.number`, which at this stage is still `0` as it has not been initialized. So it remains 0. The `number` in `Foo` is not affected because that's not the `number` that appears in this version of `multiply`.

So at the moment we have `Foo.number` at 42, and `Bar.number` at 0.

We next continue to

```
    number = y;
    multiply();
```

Which puts the 24 in `Bar.number`, then multiplies it by 3.

But the `getNumber()` is not overridden. Which means that when you call `bar.getNumber()` you'll actually be getting the `number` from the `Foo` inside it. Which is 42.

Answer (score 1):

In second case in `Foo bar = new Bar(42,24);` for `super(x)`,

```
public Foo(int x) {
   number = x;//Now number in Foo is 42
   multiply();// of Bar will be called not of Foo
   //but currently number is 0 in Bar
}
```

Indirectly `Foo#multiply();` has no effect in your second case for the `number` in `Foo`. So, `multiply();` of `Bar` is called in constructor of `Foo`, your `x` which is now `number` in `Foo` remains unchanged which is `42`. *i.e.* `Bar(100,24)` will give you number `100` in your case.

You have not override the `getNumber` in `Bar` you will have the `number` from the `Foo` which is `42`.

Worth to note that `number` in `Bar` is now `72` because of `number = y` and `multiply` method of `Bar`, which you have not used.

Your *constructor* of `Foo` is **similar to**,

```
public Foo(int x) {
  number = x;
  this.multiply();// In second case 'this' refers to Bar and not Foo
  //So that control goes to multiply method of Bar and not Foo
}
```

Comment: Even though `24 * 2` is not `42`. This guy is absolutely right. It becomes 42, because of the super(x)